# Color title in green/red depending whether list is empty or there is/are item(s)

Tags: web-part

I have a list (List A) with couple of views, lets say A, B, C.

I created webpart page and put List A in three webparts, but with different views A, B, C.
If in View A there are no items, I want to color List A title in webpart 1 in red.
If Views B and C have one or more items, I want to color List A title in webparts 2 and 3 in green.

I can use sharepoint deisgner 2013, but I cannot use visual studio.

Comment: are you using the default list view webparts? Also the title you are using is this the web part title or the title in the list view

Comment: no, as I wrote they are different views. Sorry for not being specific, each view represents view of items that specific person created. Showing items only if specific person created them. But it is public view not personal. second question I am not sure if I understood well. Title that I want to color is a list title, the one you can hide/edit/show from webpart options.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).